# Storing values inside an array in the exact index

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a binary geneology tree. I got all the downlines but wondering how will I structure them?

This is for my mlm project, I've never made such a project before so I'm completely clueless on how to set up such a binary structure.

This is what I've tried so far in my Geneology model.

```
public $leaves = array();

public function __construct() {
  $this->db = new Database;
  $this->getGenealogy($_SESSION['activationCode']);
}

public function leaves() {
  return $this->leaves;
}

public function getGenealogy($parent) {
  $result;
  $l = array();
  $this->db->sql('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorUpline = ?');
  $this->db->bindValue(1, $parent);
  $this->db->execute();
  $rows = $this->db->fetchAll();
  $result = $rows;
  foreach($result as $r) {
    array_push($this->leaves, $r->serialNumber);
    $this->getGenealogy($r->serialNumber);
  }
}
```

And this is my Dashboards controller

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->db = $this->model('Dashboard');
  $this->ddrs = $this->model('DashboardDirectReferralStructure');
  $this->bg = $this->model('Genealogy');
}

public function index() {
  $memberAccounts = $this->db->getMemberAccounts();
  $getDirectReferal = $this->ddrs->getDirectReferal();
  $leaves = $this->bg->leaves();
  $data = [
    'memberAccounts' => $memberAccounts,
    'getDirectReferal' => $getDirectReferal,
    'leaves' => $leaves
  ];
  $this->view('dashboards/dashboard', $data);
}
```

What I want to achieve is when fetching datas from the database I want to store them inside an array for referencing..

[image]

In the image above if I visualize it as an array(not multi-dimensional) we would have some thing like..

```
  array(
    [0] => '01',
    [1] => '02',
    [2] => '03',
    [3] => '04',
    [4] => 'new member',
    [5] => '06',
    [6] => '07',
    [7] => '08',
    [8] => 'new member',
    [9] => 'empty',
    [10] => 'empty',
    [11] => '12',
    [12] => '13',
    [13] => '14',
    [14] => '15'
  )
```

I put empty in [9] and [10] for that's what I'm planning for my genealogy.

However, if I put the values on my array I get this

```
      array(
    [0] => '01',
    [1] => '02',
    [2] => '03',
    [3] => '04',
    [4] => '06',
    [5] => '07',
    [6] => '08',
    [7] => '12',
    [8] => '13',
    [9] => '14',
    [10] => '15'
  )
```

So what I would like is to make an array with 15 indexes and store each and every value in their exact index, so for example value 1 will be placed on index [0] and is 2 is not present [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crzI8.jpg) would be skipped and have a 'vacant' value instead.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I could think of, You can simply save "-1" in place of "vacant or empty" values.

```
array(
    [0] => '01',
    [1] => '02',
    [2] => '03',
    [3] => '04',
    [4] => 'new member',
    [5] => '06',
    [6] => '07',
    [7] => '08',
    [8] => 'new member',
    [9] => '-1',
    [10] => '-1',
    [11] => '12',
    [12] => '13',
    [13] => '14',
    [14] => '15'
  )
```

"-1" then can be used to identify the existence of values.
Hope it helps.